# How do I force a vine to split into two vines?

Tags: vines

Malabar Spinach and other vines can get very long, but I want to force the vine to split into two so it will maximize the space. How do I do this?

Comment: Plant a second vine.  Two vines with two root systems will do far better than one with lots of branches.

Comment: i want a strong single root before I get two, and I know I can get it to root again on the other end if I keep it wet for a few days, and put it back in the ground